# Struts. Go back to same page after an action

Tags: struts, struts-action

my situation is the following:

I have a project with JSP, Struts and a lot of actions. Lets say that I have these 3 main groups {contacts.do, calendar.do and notes.do} with lot of actions in each of them. I have an action unrelated to all of them but since I didn't know where to put it I just chose contacts.

My aim is after the action, to go back to the page I was but since the action is place in contacts it returns to the default action of contacts. Is there anything I could do for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this long time ago but forgot to post it.

What I did is to redirect the action to a new JSP page. In this one only this code:

```
<script>
history.go(-1);
</script>
```

So when the page is load, it goes back to the previos visited one, as I needed.